# Concatenate queries with the Twitter gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I want to search Tweets that are both favorited in a specific account **and** contain an specific hashtag.

```
# account_name favorited tweets
Twitter.favorites('account_name')

# tweets that contain the hashtag #hashtag
Twitter.search('#hashtag').results
```

How could I build up a query to include those two?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hope there is no such methods on that gem so you can simply use `arr= Twitter.favorites('account_name') & Twitter.search('#hashtag').results` it will give the common elements from these arrays

Comment: @RajarshiDas thanks for the comment. Unfortunately I have already done that and it looks like intersection is not an option because of the way results are returned. Array elements don't match when they should. :/

Comment: both are tweets array r8? so why the intersection will not occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this:

```
Twitter.favorites('account_name').select do |tweet|
  tweet.hashtags.map(&:text).include?('my_hashtag')
end
```

Note that `my_hashtag` ***DOES NOT CONTAIN*** the `#` symbol. So if you want to filter by the hashtag `#hello` you have to use:

```
my_hashtag = 'hello'
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Awesome!